# found an error today while pushing the postgres prisma schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, prisma, supabase

While pushing the postgres prisma schema, I encountered with this error:

```
Error: Schema engine error:
**ERROR: prepared statement "s0" does not exist**
```

I was trying to push the schema to supabase

Answer (score 3):

Removing some part of connection string worked for me
This was the original string
**postgres://postgres.uqotreywxtskjqlgxapd:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543/postgres**

I removed some part from the end and converted to this
**postgres://postgres.uqotreywxtskjqlgxapd:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com**